# Grid systems coordinates alignment shift - CENTER vs CORNER/VERTEX

Tags: geometry, grid, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I was messing around in UnrealEngine with simple grid system and I asked my self how exactly should I transform/parse/align my **WorldCoordinate** to **GridCoordinate**.
For example **RedCylinder** and **BlueBox** are entities on the grid and **GridCoordinates** in my case is index of the cell in grid, assuming (0,0) is left bottom corner with X as up vector: **BlueBox** - (5,5), **RedCylinder** - (6,7)

[image: Unreal]

However UnrealEngine have its own grid that represented by WorldCoordinates, assuming that (0,0) of **MyGrid** and (0,0) of **WorldGrid** are aligned and 1:100 scale - suddenly my **RedCylinder** **GridCoord**(6,7) will have **WorldCoord**(650, 750). Obviously this is because entity is in center of the cell.

It is definitely not a problem, but I wonder is there are standarts and best practices of working with 2 Grids with different scale to each other. Right now I see 2 approaches:

1. Put entity on cell CORNER/VERTEX, however it can be necessary in some cases to have entity in cell rather then point not only visualy - for example like Inventory system or Turn-based Unit, but mechanicly as well like collision check of the **GridFloor** to entity.
2. My current implementation shifts **MyGrid** by half-size, so (0,0) is not the cell CORNER/VERTEX but CENTER. with this approach **RedCylinder.GridCoord** = (6,7) is **WorldCoord** = (600,700). However now I need to do math to align both grids - add cell-half-size to grid location. I fear this can became very complicated very fast when grid is builded in all directions around (0,0), be angled, rotated, have differente then square shape etc.

[image: Grid alignment]

My purely academic-ish question is:

**Is there are recommended approach to this kind of a problem, especialy if MyGrid will have different amount of vertexes per cell then WorldGrid (DiamonGrid, TriangleGrid)?**

Answer (score 1):

Freeze!

This is a big question (and also very interesting), but let's start by saying there is no ideal way or one true way to set it up. So there's not a single recommended approach, and I'm pretty sure that if you look into the source code of multiple grid-based games, you will probably find numerous distinctive implementations of the same thing.

But in a nutshell, you want to have two functions: one that gets a world space coordinate and gives you a grid coordinate. And another that does the inverse of that is that it receives a grid coordinate and converts it into a space coordinate.

I can tell you what I would do and point to someone who wrote a super interesting piece about how they set up their grids.

About converting from `World Coordinate` into `Grid Coordinate` and vice-versa:
If you think about it, it's a matter of converting numbers from one space coordinate system into another. That is a Linear Algebra problem. Here's an excellent video series showing a more intuitive way to think about Linear Algebra: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab

So ideally, you will have a transform that you multiply to get from World to Grid and another from Grid to World. My guess is that you only need to multiply the vectors with a scalar. So multiply by 100 to get Grid to World and 0.01 and do a floor operation to get World to Grid (or no floor if you want to know exactly where the coordinate should be in Grid Space). World to Grid will be a bit trickier as it will depend on where you define the boundaries of your grid systems.

Here's another piece of literature about coordinate systems from OpenGL. If you think about it, you're creating a new coordinate system called "Grid Space": https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems

Another thing you need to consider is that you will need to convert between World to Screen space **before** you transform into your Grid Space if your game is 2D or if it will have a fixed isometric camera.

Now, off to some links that I think you will love as this person is exploring the same problem that you are:

- https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/parts/
- https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#coordinates

I think you'll enjoy reading the references I sent, and I'm looking forward to hearing about how you set it up on your game! Again - it's just ONE way of setting it up, and there is no BEST way. The best way is probably something unique that will work for you and your architecture.

Comment: Thanks! Especialy for the redblobgames where squared grid transformed to triangle-tupled grid. I will defenetly enjoy reading those

Comment: When I saw that I was pretty sure you would love it - especially because of the author idea to build everything around square and then transform to other grids - glad you like it!